# Reading double[] values from a file

Tags: android, file

This code is a part that can save the double value to a file in a form of double[]. I want to use the saved values to draw a line graph. It should be in 'double[]' form. How can I read the saved value 'doublelist'?

--This is new code that I fixed.
  There is error in "double[] value = (double[]) ois.readObject();" line.
It says 'duplicate local variable value'

```
public static double[] getValue(){
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    List<Double> newList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double[] value;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("user_data.txt");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

       double[] value = (double[]) ois.readObject();

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        try {
            fis.close();
            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `getDoubles()` change:

```
newList = (ArrayList<Double>) ois.readObject();
```

to

```
double[] doubles = (double[]) ois.readObject();
newList = new ArrayList<Double>(doubles.length);
for (Double d : doubles) {
    newList.add(d);
}
```

The main problem here is that there isn't a very convenient way to convert and array of primitives (`double` in this case) into an array of objects (`Double` in this case).

Comment: I think I've already saved the value in double[] form in the code I've uploaded. Now, what I want is to read that data in the same form(double[]).

Comment: This does exactly that in the first line: `double[] doubles = (double[]) ois.readObject();`

Comment: Sorry, your code is confusing me, since in the code you posted you are reading and writing the same file in different formats.

Comment: I've changed the form from list<Double> to double[] before saving.

Comment: Do you still need help? or is your question answered?

Comment: I met another obstacle... When I implement the first line, there is an error at return 'doubles'. Do you know why?

Comment: I imagine that you are trying to return a double[], but the method says that it returns List<Double>. You need to make them the same.

Comment: I've changed the method as 'public static double[] getValue (){.. } but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, post your new code please. It is impossible to debug your code without seeing it.